# Why is "INTERVAL" not a valid syntax in IF statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a `IF THEN ELSE` statement in one of my stored prodecures.

```
 if (DAYOFWEEK((SELECT  DATE_ADD(_todaydate, INTERVAL (_sign * offset.value) DAY)))=7) 
 then
        SELECT  DATE_ADD(daytemp, INTERVAL (_sign * offset.value + 2) DAY) into `day`;
 elseif (DAYOFWEEK((SELECT  DATE_ADD(_todaydate, INTERVAL _sign * offset.value DAY)))=1) 
 then
        SELECT  DATE_ADD(daytemp, INTERVAL (_sign * offset.value + 1) DAY) into `day`;
 else
        Select (SELECT  DATE_ADD(_todaydate, INTERVAL _sign * offset.value DAY)) into `day`;
 END if;
```

where `_todaydate` is today's date,`_sign` is either `+1` or `-1` depending on if you want to find days in future or past and the `offset` is a number int showing how many days from `_todaydate`.

The query is meant to return me working day either in past or future depending upon the `_sign * offset.value`, but the problem is that sql returns me an error saying that `"unexpected INTERVAL (interval) in the if statement"`

I am not sure why I am getting this problem because the query it self looks fine to me. Can some one please see what I am missing...

Additional Information:

I have this IF statement in a "Select From" statement, Could that be the case of that this error is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wouldn't the code be much easier to debug and understand, if we avoided repeating long expressions, wrote something like this (to accomplish what it looks like we are trying to achieve):

```
  DECLARE _dow INT;
  DECLARE _inc INT;

  SELECT DAYOFWEEK(DATE_ADD(_todaydate, INTERVAL (_sign * offset.value) DAY)) INTO _dow ;

  CASE _dow
    WHEN 7 THEN SET _inc = 2;
    WHEN 1 THEN SET _inc = 1;
    ELSE        SET _inc = 0;
  END CASE;  

  SELECT DATE_ADD(daytemp, INTERVAL (_sign * offset.value + _inc) DAY) INTO `day`;
```

---

To answer the question you asked, "why is INTERVAL not a valid syntax in IF statement"...

I'm not aware of any restriction in MySQL stored programs that prohibits the use of the keyword INTERVAL within an IF statement. Obviously, the INTERVAL keyword isn't part of the IF construct; the keyword is only valid in the context of some expressions.

---

**FOLLOWUP**

I notice that the rewrite above is not equivalent to the original. In the original, under the ELSE condition, it's **`DATE_ADD(_todaydate,`**.  That differs from the other two conditions, where it's **`DATE_ADD(daytemp`**

A slight re-write to accommodate that difference, adding another variable `_bdt`, allows us to still just use two SELECT statements...

```
  DECLARE _bdt DATE;
  DECLARE _dow INT;
  DECLARE _inc INT;

  SELECT DAYOFWEEK(DATE_ADD(_todaydate, INTERVAL (_sign * offset.value) DAY)) INTO _dow ;

  CASE _dow
    WHEN 7 THEN 
      SET _inc = 2;
      SET _bdt = daytemp; 
    WHEN 1 THEN
      SET _inc = 1;
      SET _bdt = daytemp;
    ELSE
      SET _inc = 0;
      SET _bdt = _todaydate;
  END CASE;  

  SELECT DATE_ADD(_bdt, INTERVAL (_sign * offset.value + _inc) DAY) INTO `day`;
```

Comment: Hi spencer7593, thank you for your suggestion, I think the way you are suggesting is nicer, thank you, I will try this.

Comment: One issue with the code in my answer above.  I notice that in the original, the it's `DATE_ADD(_todaydate,...)` which differs from the `DATE_ADD(daytemp,...)` in the other two conditions. I missed that in my rewrite.  (It's not clear why that would be different. If it needs to be that way, then I'd add another procedure variable, and assign either `daytemp` or `_todaydate` in the conditional test, and then reference the new variable in just the one SELECT to get `day`.

Answer (score 3):

Shouldn't your `IF` statement be like below

```
if (SELECT DAYOFWEEK(DATE_ADD(_todaydate, INTERVAL (_sign * offset.value) DAY))=7)
```

Moreover, I see that you are repeating the same condition multiple times, eventually executing the same query multiple times. Instead have this query executed before and store the value to a local variable and use that local variable in your conditional statement rather; which would be much efficient.

Comment: Hi Rahul, thank you for the suggestions, good point, I will try this, thanks again :)